# Why does my check not work in checking for duplicated results( pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers

```html
    int main()
    {   srand(time(NULL));
        Card c;
        Card *Pc;
        Pc = new Card [52];
        Card ** someHands;
//        typedef Card * Hand;
//        Hand *someHands;
        CardtoArray(c,Pc);
        printDeckofCards(Pc,c);

    }

Card GenerateCards(Card c)
    {
        int CardNum;
        CardNum=rand() % 13 + 1;
        int colour =rand() % 4 + 1;

        switch(CardNum)
            {
                case 1: c.rank= Ace;                        
                break;

                case 2: c.rank= Two;
                break;

                case 3: c.rank= Three;
                break;

                case 4: c.rank= Four;
                break;

                case 5: c.rank= Five;
                break;

                case 6: c.rank= Six;
                break;

                case 7: c.rank= Seven;
                break;

                case 8: c.rank= Eight;
                break;

                case 9: c.rank= Nine;
                break;

                case 10: c.rank= Ten;
                break;

                case 11: c.rank= Jack;
                break;

                case 12: c.rank= Queen;
                break;

                case 13: c.rank= King;
                break;
            }
        switch(colour)
            {
                case 1:c.color="Diamond";
                break;
                case 2:c.color="Club";
                break;
                case 3:c.color="Heart";
                break;
                case 4:c.color="Spade";
                break;
            }        
            return c;

    }
```

//prints a single card this function is to be call into the function //printsdeckofcards
    void printCard(Card c)
        {

```
        cout<<*c.color;

        if(c.rank==Ace)
        cout<<"A";
        else if(c.rank==Two)
        cout<<"2";
        else if(c.rank==Three)
        cout<<"3";
        else if(c.rank==Four)
        cout<<"4";
        else if(c.rank==Five)
        cout<<"5";
        else if(c.rank==Six)
        cout<<"6";
        else if(c.rank==Seven)
        cout<<"7";
        else if(c.rank==Eight)
        cout<<"8";
        else if(c.rank==Nine)
        cout<<"9";
        else if(c.rank==Ten)
        cout<<"10";
        else if(c.rank==Jack)
        cout<<"J";
        else if(c.rank==Queen)
        cout<<"Q";
        else if(c.rank==King)
        cout<<"K";
    }
```

//generate and inserts 52 cards it also calls the function samecard to check if 
//duplicated cards have been generated and if so regenerates a new one before //inserting into the array
    void CardtoArray(Card &c,Card *Pc)
        {

```
        Card *origin;
        origin=Pc;
        for( int i=0;i<52;i++)
        {
             c=GenerateCards(c);
            if(SameCard(c,origin)==false)
            {
                *Pc=c;
                Pc++;
            }
            else
                i--;       
        }
    }




void printDeckofCards(Card *Pc,Card c)
    {
        for( int i=0;i<52;i++)
        {
            printCard(*Pc);
            cout<<" ";
            Pc++;    
        }              
    }

bool SameCard(Card c,Card *Pc)
    { bool check;

        for(int i=0; i<52; i++)
        {
            if(Pc->color==c.color && Pc->rank==c.rank)
            {
                check = true;
            }
            else
            {
                check = false;
            }
            Pc++;
        }
        return check;
    }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: And where does something "not work"?

Comment: my check function doesnt work to check if my card is duplicated before inserting into the pointer array there is always duplicated results

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are checking ALL cards, your boolean must be set to false before the loop and is set to true in the loop; it should not be set to false again in the loop:

```
bool SameCard(Card c,Card *Pc)
    { bool check= false;

        for(int i=0; i<52; i++)
        {
            if(Pc->color==c.color && Pc->rank==c.rank)
            {
                check = true;
            }
            //else
            ///{
            //  check = false;
            //}
            Pc++;
        }
        return check;
    }
```

or even:

```
bool SameCard(Card c,Card *Pc)
{
    for(int i=0; i<52; i++, pc++)
        if(Pc->color==c.color && Pc->rank==c.rank)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: OMG cant believe i spent 4 days on this thanks so much